# Forward hidden field from page through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

I've been using HttpWebRequest to get cookies and scrape websites for needed documents. I had been loading websites and then breaking them down for ViewState without too much trouble. Then I hit a snap.

The [Indiana WOTC website](https://webapps.dwd.in.gov/DWDAuthentication/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwebapps.dwd.in.gov%2FeWotc%2Fdefault-flow.htm) uses a hidden field as part of it's post return. This field is named "lt" and is randomly generated with the page. I can't load the page and grab the code since when I access the page to input the post data, the code changes.

Here is my cookie getting code;

```
private CookieContainer GetCookies(string Login_URL, List<Post_Parameters> parameters) 
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Login_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    string responseData = "";
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) 
    {
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    List<string> ParameterSet = new List<string>();
    foreach (Post_Parameters item in parameters) 
    {
        if (item.Value == "???") 
        {
            ParameterSet.Add(item.Attribute.Trim('"') + "=" + Extract(responseData, item.Attribute));
        } 
        else 
        {
            ParameterSet.Add(item.Attribute.Trim('"') + "=" + item.Value);
        }
    }
    string postData = string.Join("&", ParameterSet);
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Login_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;


    using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream())) 
    {
        requestWriter.Write(postData);
    }

    //Debug Logins
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) 
    {
        //    Console.Write(responseReader.ReadToEnd());
    }
    return cookies;
}

private string Extract(string s, string d)
{
    string viewStateNameDelimiter = d;
    string valueDelimiter = "value=\"";
    int viewStateNamePosition = s.IndexOf(viewStateNameDelimiter);
    int viewStateValuePosition = s.IndexOf(valueDelimiter, viewStateNamePosition);
    int viewStateStartPosition = viewStateValuePosition + valueDelimiter.Length;
    int viewStateEndPosition = s.IndexOf("\"", viewStateStartPosition);
    string x = "";
    x = WebUtility.UrlEncode(s.Substring(viewStateStartPosition, viewStateEndPosition - viewStateStartPosition));
    return x;
}

private struct Post_Parameters 
{
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I normally use it;

```
string LOGIN_URL = "https://wotc.jfs.ohio.gov/UserLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f";
List<Post_Parameters> x = new List<Post_Parameters>();
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", Value = "???" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "__EVENTVALIDATION", Value = "???" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "__VIEWSTATE", Value = "???" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24Fein", Value = "*****" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24UserId", Value = "*****" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24Password", Value = "*****" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24LoginButton", Value = "Log+In" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rlvBreakingNews_ClientState", Value = "" });
var i = GetCookies(LOGIN_URL, x);
```

Here is how I need to use it on Indiana's website;

```
string LOGIN_URL = "https://webapps.dwd.in.gov/DWDAuthentication/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwebapps.dwd.in.gov%2FeWotc%2Fdefault-flow.htm";
List<Post_Parameters> x = new List<Post_Parameters>();
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "username", Value = "*****" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "password", Value = "*****" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "_eventId_signIn", Value = "Sign+In" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "\"lt", Value = "Some How Post the Hidden Field from the Page" });
x.Add(new Post_Parameters { Attribute = "execution", Value = "???" });
var i = TestGetCookies(LOGIN_URL, x);
```

Basically, I need to somehow send the hidden field from the page to the POST. I think this is impossible since I'm loading the page with POST data.

Is this possible without using a WebBrowser Control? If so, how would I go about getting this to work?

Comment: Is Selenium an option?

Comment: I have a version that uses a WebBrowser control, but it's slow and prone to failure, both by code and by user. I'm switching to HttpWebRequest so I can drop the WebBrowser control as well as gain a huge speed boost. I've got it working on five other state sites so far, with this being the deceptively easy looking one that is killing the plan. I'm hoping this site is the exception, not the rule going forward. I'll know in the next few weeks.

Comment: The usual way is: `GET` the login page. Read the hidden values you need. Now `POST` all values and you are in. Thats the same thing a browser does.

Comment: I'm trying to do a GET and then a POST with the same page load but it isn't working. I get the error 'Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.' which I think means I can't do a GET and a POST in the same Create. The code changes on every Create so I need to get the code and then post it at the same time.